# about php code is running but it show wargning

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code but when i try to run it it will show the warning when delete the image
   it says "line 293 is never be empty" but it show my default no-image.jpg and that what I want it show my the default image but the warning is it show also. HOW CAN I REMOVE THAT WARNING

```
<?php
$field_image = get_field($paramdata['featfieldname'], $postid);
if (getimagesize($field_image['url']) !== false ) {
$field_imagevar =$field_image['url'];
} else {
$field_imagevar = $paramdata['themedir'].'/assets/images/no-image.jpg'; 
}
$imgtitlenew = htmlspecialchars($imgtitle, ENT_QUOTES);

?>
```

Comment: _line 293 is never be empty_ is not a PHP message. Either you've mistyped it or the message is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: what should i do please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recomended try this if the warning is Exception type, or convert your PHP error to Exception.

```
try {
  $field_image = get_field($paramdata['featfieldname'], $postid);
  if (getimagesize($field_image['url']) !== false ) {
    $field_imagevar =$field_image['url'];
  } else {
    $field_imagevar = false;
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $field_imagevar = false;
  // write additional exception handler here, logging or anyting
  // swallowing error is bad practice
}

if($field_imagevar === false) {
   $field_imagevar = $paramdata['themedir'].'/assets/images/no-image.jpg';
}
```

for a quick fix you can use @ operator (error suppression)